# Can I standardize my PCA applied count vector?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pca

I have applied `CountVectorizer()` on my `X_train` and it returned a sparse matrix.

Usually if we want to Standardize sparse matrix we pass in `with_mean=False` param.

```
scaler = StandardScaler(with_mean=False)
X_train = scaler.fit_transform()
```

But In my case after applying CountVectorizer on my `X_train` I have also performed PCA(TruncatedSVD) to reduce dimensions. Now my data is not a sparse matrix.

So now can I apply `StandardScaler()` directly without passing `with_mean=False` `(i.e with_mean=True)`?

Comment: As long as I know, data standardization is part of the PCA algorithm. So, in my point of view, you can leave `with_mean=False` as it is. Do you agree ?

Comment: @Rubens_Zimbres I don't think data standardization is part of PCA algorithm but we usually prefer to scale our data before passing it to PCA. Otherwise the magnitude to certain variables dominates the associations between the variables. Below answer does explain why we pass in `with_mean=False`. Actually I do think we can apply it directly without `with_mean` param. I was curious to see other responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a [look](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html) at what the `with_mean` parameter does, you'll find that it simply centers your data before scaling. The reason why you don't center a sparse matrix is because when you try to center a sparse matrix it will get transformed into a dense matrix and will occupy much more memory, thus destroying its sparsity in the first place.

After you perform PCA your data has reduced dimensions and can now be centered before scaling. So yes, you can apply `StandardScaler()` directly.